# "<global-exceptions> <exception key= " does not pick up language specific value

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-config

On login page there is is drop down for language selection and each language has its specific property file setup and default is english

Now what happens :

1. User is at login page and selects chinese from drop down.
2. Entire page is refreshed with chinese.
3. Login fails , the failed login message appears in english instead of chinese.

That's because in the struts-config.xml , exception key looks up the default property file instead of language specific property file.

Please find the action class also below and JSP representation.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to specify in struts-config.xml to pick based key-value pair from language specific property files ?
2. How do i change action class to look up for key in lang specific property file ?
3. Alter `<html:errors/>` to obtain the key and then lookup in jsp?

**struts-config.xml**

```
<global-exceptions>
    <exception 
        key="global.error.invalidKey"
        path="/login.jsp"
        scope="request"
        type="default.package.InvalidLoginException"/>
</global-exceptions>
```

**InvalidLoginException**

```
 import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
 import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

 public class InvalidLoginException extends Exception {
  private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog("default.package.InvalidLoginException");

  public InvalidLoginException( String msg ){
  super( msg );
 log.warn(msg);
 }
}
```

**In JSP**

```
<html:errors/>
```

Answer (score 0):

specify

```
<message-resources
        parameter="path for properties file" />
```

in struts.xml

[see here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-internationalizing-or-localization-example/)

Comment: The <message-resources is set and works fine for rest of the application. It does not seem to affect the look up of <global-exceptions>
        <exception  :-(    Thank you for quick reply.